# Grant SD permissions to an app

Tags: android, permissions

How can I give write permissions to SD for my App.  I have Android 5.1.1 and my device is a Sony XPeria.

Error appear is the next:
https://paste.originersmc.com/10/

Comment: you should read this .https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Google Guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Basically, all you need is this permission in your manifest:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hello,
I added that permission, but error persist.
Solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can request permissions at runtime too, Hence defining permission is neccessory as well.
Here is how you can request Runtime Permisison.

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For 5.1.1 you need to just Add permission to manifest xml

```
<manifest>

     //For Write to External storage
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

     //For Read from External storage
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

           ...
     <application>
            ...
            <activity> 
                ...
            </activity>
     </application>
</manifest>
```

But later than 6.0 you need to add permission runtime too.

Comment: Have you got your solution? @OriginersMc

Comment: No, I added code
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
but, when app try modify SD, it says: "Permission Denied"

Comment: All code, I can't. but,
If I send you my androidmanifest.xml file, you can help me?

Comment: Yes, Edit your Question and add manifest file and java file too.

Comment: Check my androidmanifest: https://paste.originersmc.com/7/

(This paste, will be deleted after this problem was fixed for security reason)!

Comment: Okey. Also add `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission than try.

Comment: Hi, I tried adding that perm, and it continue without work. Actual manifest: https://paste.originersmc.com/8/

Comment: will you add java file also??

Comment: Java file name please?

Comment: I don't know who files have that error, but error is:
https://paste.originersmc.com/10

Comment: `DownloadManagerImpl.java` file

Comment: Hi, file you ask: https://paste.originersmc.com/11/       
You can create an past using https://paste.originersmc.com/ (use it to show the new config file)

Comment: You've the solution?

Comment: Can you share the value of `mission.location` what it is? in `DownloadManagerImpl.java` line number `39` and `41`